# What are the side effects of using multiple instances of a single id name in HTML?

Tags: html

Just curious to find out exactly what problems I'll cause myself if I include multiple elements in my web-page with the same id?

for example:

```
<div id='someID'>Some Content</div>
<div id='someID'>Some Other Content</div>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I don't but it's nice to know why I don't.

Comment: Minor comment: it's an accepted HTML convention to use doublequotes rather than singlequotes to delimit attribute values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you try and reference those elements from JavaScript it won't be able to resolve which element you are referring to. Depending on the specific JavaScript interpreter you are running on, you may either get errors, or undefined behaviour - both cases are undesirable.

The HTML spec states that Id's should be unique, so your HTML will be considered as invalid and may cause browsers to drop back into quirks mode rendering, or even totally refuse to render your page (although that's not likely, and all current browsers will render something - technically, if you don't follow the spec the browser is under no obligation to do anything but reject your page).

You should consider using class names instead if you want something to identify multiple elements by:

```
<div class="someClass">Some Content</div>
<div class="someClass">Some Other Content</div>
```

---

[Blair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/191306/blair-mcmillan) has pointed out in the comments below that if you need to search for elements by class from JavaScript, you can speed the search up by going from the nearest element with an ID and also tell it what node type to look for. This can keep the access speed fast in a lot of cases, but doesn't break any rules on duplicate id's:

```
HTML:
<div id="myNearestID">
    <div class="someClass">Some Content</div>
    <div class="someClass">Some Other Content</div>
</div>

JavaScript+JQuery:
$('#myNearestID div.someClass')
```

Comment: true, there's no native javascript to target elements by class though. jQuery is super slow to go though them, so it's not exactly the same thing.

Comment: I gets a lot faster though if you go from the nearest element with an ID and also tell it what node type to look for. `$('#myNearestID div.someClass')` in this case.

Comment: @user278457: Yes, but if you use duplicate Id's there is no guarantee it will even work. It's like saying you want to use the same URL for two websites because it saves having to do multiple DNS lookups. What would you rather have, fast, or correct. @Blair. Nice suggestion. Thanks for that, I'll include it in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I know about searching for the nearest parent div with an ID. Thanks for bringing it up though.

Comment: Incidently, jQuery accepts a second value to specify a context, that does the same thing.
ie:

$('#nearestID div.someClass') OR $('div.someClass','#nearestID')

Answer (score 6):

IE will have major problems with any javascript using IDs, that's the main side-effect.

Overall, IDs are unique, per the spec...the browser maker is free to make this assumption in their code, and **any** bugs (Javascript, CSS, etc) that result from invalid HTML involving them...well, that's your problem :)

The browser isn't obligated to fix it really, and I don't think they should either.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure how browsers render the CSS rules of type `#someID` in such case (they will probably apply the rule to all such elements), but you’ll certainly run in trouble with JavaScript and `getElementById`.

Answer (score 1):

I read elsewhere that IE creates a global variable for each element with an ID.

Am I wrong in saying that's an issue too?

Answer (score 1):

A couple more points not already noted.

Fragment identifiers: How would the browser handle a link to http://www.example.com#someID ?

Internal references : If someID was on two input elements, and you had <label for="someID">... if the user clicked on the label, the browser would have to decide which input should receive focus. (In HTML5, this is defined to be the first input, which is not necessarily what you want). Likewise for ARIA support, some attributes such as aria-labelledby and aria-describedby rely on pointing to a single place.

Comment: I learned my html in 1994, back then www.example.com#someID would jump to <a name="someID">Section headline</a>. Did that changed over the years? I did not know you can jump to a tag by specifying its id in the Url.

Comment: Yes. HTML4.01 spec says "Destination anchors in HTML documents may be specified either by the A element (naming it with the name attribute), or by any other element (naming with the id attribute)." In HTML5, the "name" attribute on the "a" element is obsolete. (http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/obsolete.html#obsolete)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this change in HTML5 before.

Comment: +1 I didn't know that either and have been adding unnecessary anchor tags for years!

Answer (score 0):

Then which one control you want to refer when you do something like this in Javascript:-

```
document.getElementById("someID")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the browsers will complain, but the other problems you would observe are:

- The page might not validate due to dulicate ID declaration
- The javascript's which might be running on the page might stop working correctly if they are finding elements by ID since at this time, it will get the wrong element
- The CSS rules applied at #ID will be repeated to all the elements which have the same ID

I think these are enough problems to warrant not using the same ID across all elements.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Browser will go mad when we are referencing it through JavaScript or somewhere else in code-behind file.