# xpath to exclude elements that have a class

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument

I'm trying to select all dom elements that have `id="mydiv"` but exclude the ones that also have the `class="exclass"`. Right now I'm doing the first part `//*[@id="mydiv"]`. How do I add the class exclusion part?

P.S. In case you're wondering why I need to select multiple elements that have the same id, I'm just working on an existing DOM that I can't control.

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same id? That's not healthy, you know. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487074/what-are-the-side-effects-of-using-multiple-instances-of-a-single-id-name-in-htm

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use negation:

```
//*[@id="mydiv" and @class!="exclass"]
```

If the `class` attribute may not exist on all nodes, you need this:

```
//*[@id="mydiv" and (not(@class) or @class!="exclass")]
```

The last (somewhat) odd logic can be turned into what Michael proposed:

```
//*[@id="mydiv" and not(@class="exclass")]
```

Though, personally, the fact that XPath cannot make comparisons if the attribute is missing feels a bit like a shortcoming.

Comment: This isn't quite what the user asked for. Downvoting. See my answer.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated my answer; as mentioned in my update, I feel that having a "nothing cannot be compared with anything" is somewhat of a shortcoming of xpath; just can't think of any reason why that behavior would be useful :/

Answer (score 9):

The answer to the question as written is

```
//*[@id="mydiv" and not(@class="exclass")]
```

The first half of the condition is true if there is an @id attribute and its value is mydiv. The second half is true if there is no @class attribute with the value exclass: that is, if there is no class attribute, or if there is a class attribute and its value is something other than "exclass".

Avoid using != in this situation: 90% of the time, if you think of writing `A!=B`, you probably wanted `not(A=B)`. The meaning is different in the case where either A or B is not a singleton, that is, where it is either empty, or can contain multiple values.